# Content grouping based on time and theme

Tags: usability, layout, hierarchy, content

I have some articles which need to be arranged on a new website based on **time and theme**. For example on a blog site the content is usually arranged by date (descending latest first) - see first figure on the left.

[image]

Other examples of content display might be by tag, category, most popular (viewed / shared), most relevant etc.

The content I'm trying to display will be all based around a *current* theme. i.e. space. So the content could be arranged in many different ways and Im trying to work out what would work best. Some of these ideas have be mocked in the figure below.

- All in that theme at top followed by each other theme in alphabetical or latest article published order
- All in current theme followed by articles by date in many other theme (similar) to latest content like a blog)
- NOT all in theme (as we may run the theme twice over a couple of years etc) - showing just the new content since theme re-initiated, followed by other themes etc.
- etc...?

Also how would this be communicated visually? (different themed content having different border colours for example).

Comment: I'm lost starting 3rd paragraph.  What exactly is "current" theme?  And why is it "i.e. Space"?  What does "All in theme" or "each other theme" mean?  What do you mean by "theme re-initiated"?  I'm just struggling to understand. Maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using themes, you can treat them as "tags" where the user can quickly identify which article is linked to what topic. You can colour-code it like the example below to make it easier for the user to identify what article belongs to what tag.

People need to quick identify how is the content organized, and if your tags are very different, i.e."spaceships", "make-up", "advanced engineering" and "cats". Probably the user will not want to see the other content just to find the spaceship at the bottom. This example is a bit radical but most users will be interested in a set of your tags, not in all of them.

I recommend some sort of "navigation bar" that quickly tell the user what they can find there and how to find it.

If it's a blog-type page, users will be used to have the content arrange by time of creation. So, the most recently published one first. People like seeing the new stuff first.

[image]

Comment: Cool thanks Rosie, think we'll roll some sort of colour signifier across the articles, and see how that looks within the articles overview page. Any other ideas welcome.